# Passing an attribute based on property giving warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am calling `<SearchableList>` component like this

```
<SearchableList
    pullToRefresh=""
    items={groupStates}
    searchFields={groupStateSearchFields}
    searchTemplate={() => <GroupStateSearchEntry />}
    itemTemplate={x => <GroupStateItem key={x.groupName} groupState={x} />} />
```

And somewhere like this

```
<SearchableList
    items={items}
    searchFields={searchFields}
    searchTemplate={() => <SearchEntry />}
    pullToRefresh="conversations"
    itemTemplate={item => <ConversationItem key={item.id} item={item}
        isSelected={this.state.isArchiving && this.state.selectedConversations.indexOf(item.id) >= 0}
        onPressItem={this.pressItem} onLongPressItem={this.longPressItem} accountTimeZone={this.store.accountTimeZone} />} />
```

As you can see that I am passing an attribute `PullToRefresh`. It can either be blank or "conversations". In my component, I as checking it like this

```
<ScrollView 
    ref={(ref) => this._refScrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={this.scrollToEnd}
    refreshControl={
        (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') &&
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
}>
    {!this.state.isBusy && !this.state.items.length && (
        <View>
            {!!blankItemTemplate && blankItemTemplate() || <BlankItem />}
        </View>
    )}
    {!!this.state.items.length && (
        <List items={this.state.items} itemTemplate={itemTemplate} />
    )}
</ScrollView>
```

But I am getting this error whenever my 'PullToRefresh' is "" over here

```
refreshControl={
    (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') &&
    <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
    />
}
```

Please see this link for reference

> http://prntscr.com/jxgd3k

Comment: what is your `this.state.refreshing` type?

Comment: it is boolean. true / false

Comment: Whats the prop type of refreshControl in ScrollView

Comment: const { searchTemplate, itemTemplate, blankItemTemplate, shouldScrollToEnd, pullToRefresh } = this.props;

Comment: It is by default "any"

Comment: from the warning what i understand is you are trying to render refreshControl  but '&&' returns a boolean .

Comment: Yeah but I can not seem to figure it out

Comment: use a ternary operator  (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') ? <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
    />:null

Comment: @Karthik thankyou. Using turnary operator worked like a charm.

Comment: @AliZia glad that it worked. added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using && passes false if pullToRefresh != 'conversations' which react can not render. Pass null if there is nothing to render

```
   (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') ?
         <RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh=this._onRefresh.bind(this)} />:null
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is here

```
refreshControl={
    (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') &&
    <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
    />
}
```

if  **pullToRefresh** value is **""** **refreshControl** will have the value of **false** because it doesn't have a default value so the statement evaluate to false   and **ScrollView** expect a React element not a boolean so you need to change your code so refeshControl should have a default value you can use if statement before the return value of the render function to something like this

```
const refreshControl = <span>here your default value</span>;
if (pullToRefresh === 'conversations') {
    refreshControl = (
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
    );
}
```

now refreshControl has a default value and you should based on ScrollView component take my example as a reference to modify your code

Comment: How can I pass this IF inside the component?

Comment: Define the variable and use the if statement before the return value of the render function after that pass the variable itself to component like this 

const refreshControl = <span>here your default value</span>;
if (pullToRefresh === 'conversations') {
    refreshControl = (
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
    );
}

return <ScrollView refreshControl ={refreshControl }

Comment: can you please write that as an answer?